# Filter UITableView Feed via tap on Slide Out Menu with protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, protocols

Imagine you have a slide out menu.  When you type on an item from this slide out menu, you want to use the NSString located in that slide out menu item to filter out the feed of your app, a UITableView filled with custom cells.

You believe that the right way to do that is with a protocol and delegate.

In your slide out menu view controller, you declare the protocol, the associated method (implemented in your feed view controller) and the delegate.

```
//  SlideOutMenuTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SlideOutMenuItems.h"
#import "SlideOutMenuCellTableViewCell.h"

@protocol filterFeed <NSObject>

-(void)filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:(NSString   *)slideOutItemStringData; //String to pass slideOut menu item string back to feed
@end

@interface SlideOutMenuTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic,assign)id<filterFeed> stringDelegate;

@end
```

In your feed view controller, you have the following header and implementation files:

```
//  FeedVCTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlameCellTableViewCell.h"
#import "Feed.h"
#import "SlideOutMenuTableViewController.h"
#import "FlameDetailViewController.h"

@interface FeedVCTableViewController : UITableViewController<FlameCellDelegate, senddataProtocol, filterFeed,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate>

@property Feed *feed;
@property Feed *filteredFeed;
@property NSInteger *indexTapCell;


@end




//  FeedVCTableViewController.m


#import "FeedVCTableViewController.h"
#import "Feed.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface FeedVCTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation FeedVCTableViewController

// First quite a few methods not relevant to solve this

#pragma mark - Filter feed based on slideout menu item tapped

-(void)filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:(NSString *)slideOutItemStringData
{
    NSLog(@"filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped just started");
    if (!(slideOutItemStringData == (nil)))
        {//Pass self.feed.flames + filtering string ==> filtered flames
        NSMutableArray* allFlames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.feed.flames];
        NSString *flameRelationFilter = slideOutItemStringData;
        NSPredicate* sortFlames = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(kFlameRelation like %@)", flameRelationFilter];
        NSArray* filteredFlames = [allFlames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sortFlames];
        NSLog(@"The filter flames are %@", filteredFlames);
        NSMutableArray *mutableFilteredFlames = [filteredFlames mutableCopy];
        self.filteredFeed.flames = mutableFilteredFlames;

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}

//Other methods not relevant here

@end
```

Last but not least, you call your protocol method in the slide out menu after verifying that the NSString that you are looking to pass to your stringDelegate is of class NSString and is passing the intended value (the NSString located inside the tapped sell):

```
#pragma mark - segue method

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Filter_MenuItem"]) {

        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[SlideOutMenuCellTableViewCell class]])
        {
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
            NSLog(@"The indexPath of slideout cell is: %@", indexPath);
            NSLog(@"class for object sender: %@", NSStringFromClass([sender class]));


        //Assign tapped cell string to stringDelegate
        NSLog(@"The NSString in the slide out menue item cell is %@",[self.slideOutMenuItems menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    if([[self.slideOutMenuItems menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"The string of the tapped menu items is kind of class NSString");
    }
    NSLog(@"The stringDelegate value prior to executing the delegate method is %@",stringDelegate);
      [stringDelegate filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:[self.slideOutMenuItems menuItemAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       NSLog(@"The stringDelegate from the slide out menu VC has been set to %@", stringDelegate);

    }



}

}
```

You make sure to synthesize your delegate in this latter implementation too:

```
@implementation SlideOutMenuTableViewController
@synthesize stringDelegate;
```

You launch your build and it crashed with the following error message:

```
2015-10-13 15:15:06.245 Flame[1607:479051] The NSString in the slide out menue item cell is Friend into
2015-10-13 15:15:06.245 Flame[1607:479051] The string of the tapped menu items is kind of class NSString
2015-10-13 15:15:06.245 Flame[1607:479051] The stringDelegate value prior to executing the delegate method is All Flames
2015-10-13 15:15:13.270 Flame[1607:479051] -[__NSCFConstantString filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100306d10
2015-10-13 15:15:13.272 Flame[1607:479051] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100306d10'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183e94f5c 0x19899bf80 0x183e9bc6c 0x183e98c14 0x183d9cdcc 0x1000e0d0c 0x189ad9c78 0x189ad9ae0 0x189ad9da8 0x18951dc6c 0x1895d8f8c 0x189694828 0x1896a0dc8 0x1893dd1c8 0x183e4bc30 0x183e499d4 0x183e49e04 0x183d78dc0 0x18eecc088 0x189452f44 0x1000e05ec 0x1991c68b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How can you fix it?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you should be paying attention to is this:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100306d10
```

This is telling you that you're trying to send the `filterFeedFromSlideOutItemTapped:` message on a string, which obviously isn't going to work.

You aren't showing where you set this delegate property to an instance that conforms to the `filterFeed` protocol, so that's where you need to look next.

**Update:**

To properly set this up, it really depends on if you're using Storyboards or building everything in code. If you're setting it up in code, then you need to find the common parent that creates these 2 controllers (which might be a navigation controller or a split view controller) and put the delegate set up there.

If you're using storyboards you can wire up delegates in the designer.

Failing either of these options, you can have your tableview reach out into the view controller hierarchy and find the slide out controller, setting the property that way, but this isn't really ideal.

Comment: Hi @Ben Scheirman:  Thanks!  I am struggling with where to set the delegate since I don't have a segue (where I usually set protocol delegates, and it works).  Would value some more guidance as I am trying to figure something out.  As you can tell, I am a startup entrepreneur, self-taught looking to make it work, even if it's not pretty! :)

Comment: Thanks for having updated your response with more details.  This is helpful.